# Meaning of Google Assistant specific Android Manifest configuration?

Tags: android-manifest, google-assistant

I have a sample app with enabled Google Assistant and it contains following manifest file settings for Google Assistant:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="android.media.tv" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/recorded_program" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/channel" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/channel" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/program" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/program" />
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/recorded_program" />
</intent-filter>
```

What are the meanings for these intent-filter data?
I mean

```
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/recorded_program" />
```

occurs twice!? Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, the double is typo